# Prove that the general linear group, GL(V) is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If V is a vector space and GL(V) is the set of all linear transformations from V to V that are bijections, prove that GL(V) is a group with operation composition.

I am out of practice with algebra, and perhaps this is too abstract for me, but isn't the fact that the linear transformations are bijections, isn't associativity and inverse proved? But to prove the existence of an identity element?

Comment: The identity map is the group's unit.

Comment: You have to show the inverse is linear, though.

Comment: Composition of linear transformations is matrix multiplication.  Not all linear transformations have inverses.  (Do you remember the tests if a matrix is invertable?)

Comment: @saulspatz I suppose my problem is that I'm not sure how to do that in such abstract terms.

Comment: The object is not to do it in abstract terms. The object is to take an element of $GL(V)$, describe its inverse, and prove its inverse is an element of $GL(V)$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $T \in GL(V)$. We wish to show that $S := T^{-1}$ is a linear map.

Proof: Let $w, w' \in V$. Then, since $T$ is a bijection, there exists $v, v' \in V$ such that $w = T(v)$ and $w' = T(v')$. Then, $S(w) * S(w') = S(T(v)) * S(T(v')) = v*v' = S(T(v*v')) = S(T(v)*T(v')) = S(w*w')$.

Comment: $V$ isn't necessarily $k^n$, so we can't identify $GL(V)$ with $GL_n(k)$ without choosing a basis

Comment: I've been thinking this as well. I will edit.

Comment: This has nothing to do with determinants . A  bijection  means -has an inverse under composition .You do have to show the inverse is linear .

Comment: Edited to show just the inverse is linear.